# Synchronizing Sql Server Database with Pi System Database

Tags: sql-server, database, osisoft

I'm developing a tool to synchronize SQL Server database with a PI System (OleDb).Each time there is a change in the PI System I need to update the values in SQL Server Database and vice-versa. Could you please provide me with the options possible and how it can be done.

Thanks,
M.K

Answer (score 1):

At this time this can be done through the **Relational Database (RDBMS via ODBC) Interface from OSI Soft**.The interface allows bi-directional transfer of data between the PI System and any Relational Database Management System (RDBMS) that supports Open DataBase Connectivity (ODBC) drivers. The interface runs on Microsoft Windows operating systems, and is able to connect to any PI Server node available on the network.

I have used this interface and it is very stable. In the [OSI PI YouTube Learning Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YePNMUKoyrY&list=PLMcG1Hs2JbcuR_UEb5IGY3fenO6CfPlhX), they have a series of videos where they take you step-by-step in the installation and configuration process of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an EventPipe on your data and every time a new or edited event comes in you could push that out to the SQL Server.